# Pod lib lint did not pass validation xcodebuild: ld: warning: ignoring file missing required architecture i386 in file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Recently, I'm trying to use CocoaPods to upload an integrated sharedSDK to a private library.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something stupid. When I run "pod lib lint", everything seems to be fine but when I run "pod spec lint" I get:

ld: warning: ignoring file by  TencentOpenAPI.framework

```
      ** BUILD FAILED **


    The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/melody/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fcbstzvalzvjwfgtkwkycnyvprjk
/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/App normal i386
    (1 failure)
     -> SLShareSDK (0.1.0)
        - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/melody/GItLab/SLShareSDK/SLShareSDK/Assets/TencentOpenAPI.framework/TencentOpenAPI,
 missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/melody/GItLab/SLShareSDK/SLShareSDK/Assets/TencentOpenAPI.framework/TencentOpenAPI (3 slices)
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[!] SLShareSDK did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
```

The contents of my SLShareSDK.Sperepo file are

```
  Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'SLShareSDK'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'Intergation'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO:  SLShare...
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'http://gitlaBalaBala...'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Melody' => 'BalaBala.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'http://gitlab.balabala...../SLShareSDK.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }


  s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'

  s.source_files = 'SLShareSDK/Classes/**/*'
  s.ios.vendored_libraries = 'SLShareSDK/Assets/*.a'
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'SLShareSDK/Assets/TencentOpenAPI.framework'
   s.resource_bundles = {
     'SLShareSDK' => ['SLShareSDK/Assets/*.bundle']
   }

   s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'SystemConfiguration','Security','CoreTelephony','ImageIO'
   s.libraries  = 'sqlite3','z.1.2.8','c++.1'

   s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.3'
end
```

Here is the directory structure ：

```
├── SLShareSDK
│   ├── Assets
│   │   ├── TencentOpenAPI.framework
│   │   │   ├── Headers
│   │   │   ├── Resources
│   │   │   └── TencentOpenAPI
│   │   ├── libWeChatSDK.a
│   │   └── libWeiboSDK.a
│   └── Classes
│       └── SLShareSDK
│           ├── AFHTTPRequestOperationManager+JXExtentsion.h
│           ├── AFHTTPRequestOperationManager+JXExtentsion.m
│           ├── SLShare.h
│           ├── SLShare.m
│           ├── SLShareAuthorizeObject.h
│           ├── SLShareAuthorizeObject.m
│           ├── SLShareConfiguration.plist
│           ├── SLShareConstant.h
│           ├── SLShareConstant.m
│           ├── SLShareContentObject.h
│           ├── SLShareContentObject.m
│           ├── SLShareContentObjectTranslater.h
│           ├── SLShareContentObjectTranslater.m
│           ├── SLShareQQ.h
│           ├── SLShareQQ.m
│           ├── SLShareSina.h
│           ├── SLShareSina.m
│           ├── SLShareWeChat.h
│           ├── SLShareWeChat.m
│           ├── WBHttpRequest+WeiboGame.h
│           ├── WBHttpRequest+WeiboShare.h
│           ├── WBHttpRequest+WeiboToken.h
│           ├── WBHttpRequest+WeiboUser.h
│           ├── WBHttpRequest.h
│           ├── WBSDKBasicButton.h
│           ├── WBSDKCommentButton.h
│           ├── WBSDKRelationshipButton.h
│           ├── WXApi.h
│           ├── WXApiObject.h
│           ├── WechatAuthSDK.h
│           ├── WeiboSDK+Statistics.h
│           ├── WeiboSDK.h
│           └── WeiboUser.h
├── SLShareSDK.podspec
```

Q1.:

In my Opinion,
   The Program Use the TencentOpenAPI.framework and I aleady set `s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'SLShareSDK/Assets/TencentOpenAPI.framework'` make sure the code path currect.

And I Use `pod lib lint --use-libraries  --verbose`  Check Out the Specrepo

But it show error make me crazed.But the way,The Same code I Use xcode run without problems.

So,This is my situation, thank you for your attention and help, if you have some suggestion please help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when i try to link it agains third party framework, i found no solution but have to take out the header files alone out to let the lib build without linking, after that it work, would like to know a better solution though, see [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5854) for more info, also contain a fix by changing the `validator.rb`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found out the problem, as the error mentioned in the latest TencentOpenAPI.framework does not support i836CPU, so I try to use the old API to run, it's working!!!. But I do not know how to change   pod lib lint  does not run the i836 compiler...